# Find the negation of the definition of uniform continuity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

We know that:
A function $f$ is uniformly continuous on a set $\mathbb{E}$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}$ if:
For every $\varepsilon$ $>$ 0, there is a number $\delta$ $>$ 0 such that for all x, x' $\in$ $\mathbb{E}$, $|f(x')-f(x)|$ $<$ $\varepsilon$ whenever | − ′| < .

Written using symbols: ($\forall$ $\varepsilon$ $>$ 0)($\exists$ $\delta$ $>$ 0)($\forall$ x, x' $\in$ $\mathbb{E}$)($|x-x'|$ $<$ $\delta$ $\Longrightarrow$ $|f(x')-f(x)|$ $<$ $\varepsilon$) (is it correct?)

The statement's negation is: A function $f$ is not uniformly continuous on a set $\mathbb{E}$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}$ if there exists $\varepsilon$ $>$ 0 such that for every $\delta$ $>$ 0 there are x, x' $\in$ $\mathbb{E}$ with $|x-x'|$ $<$ $\delta$ $\Longrightarrow$ $|f(x')-f(x)|$ $<$ $\varepsilon$. (?)

Written using symbol: $|x-x'|$ $<$ $\delta$ $\wedge$ $\sim$ $|f(x')-f(x)|$ $<$ $\varepsilon$ (?)

Please check if the answers are correct. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there! You have only forgotten to deny the last statement.

Since $p\to q$ is equivalent to $\neg p\vee q$, the negation of $p\to q$ is $p\wedge\neg q$.

At your case, we say that $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ if there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ s.t. for every $\delta > 0$ there are $x\in E$ and $y\in E$ with $|x - y| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(y)|\geq \varepsilon$.